# Find turns in GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, geojson

Given coordinates, I would like to find jibes/gybes in the coordinates. I will use it to calculate how fast the jibe was.

If we look at [this file](https://github.com/surflog-tech/geospeed/blob/main/assets/jibe.json), visualized below, shortened from [this](https://tracklog.surflog.app/processed/8c88332c-ff17-5a24-b3f1-ef1cde0cc4e7.json) GeoJSON file, we humans can easily see that as a turn, but how can I code my way to that?

If you can guide me with pseudocode, I should be able to write that in JavaScript and will provide it in [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@surflog/geospeed) package.

[image: jibe]

Comment: You could compute the bearing at each point of the geojson, keep track of it and search for changes.

Comment: @TimothyDalton The changes are always very small between each pair of vertices though, so its necessary to do smoothing and thresholding (and maybe clustering) too. The crucial thing will be deciding how to discriminate true gybes from other turns. Maybe look for an angular change of Z degrees in all moving lengths of X metres. Have been exploring a bit using R... Will post if I get anything concrete!

Comment: See here for a similar problem that addresses some of the points risen by @Spacedman  gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814 - especially the 3rd and 5th screenshot look like what you want to do.

Comment: This turf.js library has a bearing function and a distance function.  Your data points have times and locations.  Pick a time span appropriate for the hull speed of the vessel. Generate the bearing between point 1 those the chosen time/point 2.  If the distance between those two points is sufficient (the boat is not dead in the water and drifting)  and bearing angle is sufficient call it a turn?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it can be achieved using QGIS:

1. Convert the file to a geopackage (line geometry) using QGIS.
2. Remove unnecessary fields (they can slow down further processing).
3. Set the correct coordinate system in meters, (not degrees). In your example: EPSG:32632 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N.
4. Use the [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) tool to get point layers containing distances and angles between vertices.
5. Then you can apply this algorithm to find jibes:

If the distance between points `N` and `M` is smaller than value `D` and the angle varies more then the value `A` then all points between points `N` and `M` are jibe.

[image]

Comment: What are `M`, `N`, `A`, and `D` in the diagram?

Comment: @Matt These values are not shown in the diagram (my mistake). They are abstract values: `D` is the distance in meters between points `N` and `M`; `A` is the angle by which the direction between points `N` and `M` changes. By design, `D` and `A` should be manually adjusted to fit the gybe criterion (from a human point of view).

Comment: Great, thanks for the extra info.