# Can Sort and Number QGIS plugin be performed as a batch process?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, batch, plugins

I need to add a field into these shapefile rows which are sequentially numbered when ordered by either the X or Y axis.

I have had success with this by using the sort and number QGIS plugin, however I have only managed to be able to perform this manually row by row. My full dataset will have over 100 rows, so is there a way to be able to perform this as a batch process?

Other processes I have executed the batch process from the toolbox with a right click, but as it is a plugin, I can't find a way to perform this.

[image: Point data in rows]

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: In my opinion, the approach to solving the problem is very much like this:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/409386/35561

Comment: I see your problem has been solved, but if you have multiple features in a single layer and would like to renumber by following a custom line instead of x/y coords, you can also try this virtual layer method outlined here (still dreaming for the day some smart cookie can convert this to a python plugin). https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328813/98784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pyqgis. This will process all layers added to the map and add an id field and numbering. Adjust fieldname and wether to sort by x or y and only add the shapes you want to process to the map:

```py
fieldname = 'idfield' #Name of the field to add

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For all layers added to the map (add only the shapefiles)
    print(layer)
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname, QVariant.Int)]) #Add the new field
    layer.updateFields()
    fieldindex = layer.fields().indexOf(fieldname) #Find index of the new field
    all_features = [f for f in layer.getFeatures()] #List all features/points
    all_features.sort(key=lambda f: f.geometry().asPoint().x()) #Sort by x coordinate. Change .x to .y to sort by y coord
    attributemap = {} #A dictionary to hold feature id, fieldindex and number
    for e, f in enumerate(all_features, 1):
        attributemap[f.id()] = {fieldindex: e} #
    #{30: {6: 1}, 28: {6: 2},... } So feature 30 should in field 6 get the value 1
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap) #Update the new field with numbers
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding - I'm very new to python but I have finally figured it out and got it working, it gives exactly what I need so thank you very much!